# Почему метод класса возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

При вызове метода `move` он выводит в консоль нужный результат и `None`. Откуда интерпретатор берет `None`?

```
 class Auto:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    name = ''
    weight = 0
    max_speed = 0

    def __init__(self,x,y,weight,max_speed,name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.weight = weight
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Автомобиль ' + str(self.name) + ' ' + 'вес авто = ' + str(self.weight) + 'кг  ' + 'макс. скорость = ' + str(self.max_speed) + 'км/ч'

    def move(self,x,y):
        print('Движение автомобиля в точку ', x, y)

renault = Auto(1, 2, 1500, 220, 'renault')

print(renault.move(15, 20))
print(renault)
```

Comment: Ну вот, стоит на совещание отойти, так тут же наотвечают вместо того чтобы дубликат поискать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def move(self,x,y):
    print('Движение автомобиля в точку ',x,y)

print(renault.move(15,20))
```

Метод `move` ничего не возвращает через `return`, поэтому `Python` считает, что метод возвращает `None`. Соответственно, `print(renault.move(15,20))` этот `None` и печатает.

Answer (score 3):

У вас в функции нет `return`:

```
def move(self,x,y):
    print('Движение автомобиля в точку ',x,y)
```

но вернуть-то что-то нужно?.. вот оно и возвращает `None`

Кстати, `return print('Движение автомобиля в точку ',x,y)` не сработает: функция print возвращает `None` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Если в функции не прописан return — она возвращает None. Функция в питоне всегда возвращает что-то. Вы вероятно хотите:

```
def move(self, x, y):
    return ('Движение автомобиля в точку ', x, y)
```